# What are some invariants/properties of the conjugacy classes of the symmetric group $S_n$?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, integer-partitions

I've recently realized that there is an [isomorphism](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_symmetric_group:S8) between the integer partitions of $n$ and the symmetric group $S_n$. There are many [documented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#See_also) properties of integer partitions of $n$ but I can't seem to find much similar prior work on conjugacy classes of $S_n$. I'm hoping to use these properties of the conjugacy classes to find some insights on some research I'm doing.

I've spent a couple of days trying to define invariants myself but can't seem to produce many that are useful.

I have a feeling this is work that's been explored before but I don't have the correct vocabulary to describe it well enough to find it. Or maybe I'm taking the wrong approach entirely. Can someone please help me out? Thanks!

(The partition research in question is [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.2192.pdf))

**EDIT**: I'm adding this to hopefully make this question more clear:

Regardless of everything I've mentioned, all I'm looking for is properties of conjugacy classes formed in $S_n$ by cycle type.

For instance, partitions of integer $n$ have many studied properties such as [durfee square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durfee_square), [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_a_partition), [crank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank_of_a_partition), etc...

But I can't seem to find any information on any useful/nontrivial properties of conjugacy classes in the corresponding group $S_n$. I'm hoping that someone more experienced can help point me to useful properties as I can't seem to find much prior art. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what is the isomorphism you've recently realized?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Cycle type determines conjugacy class](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cycle_type_determines_conjugacy_class)

Comment: @Berci, I've added the link to an example of the isomorphism I'm describing. I haven't written or read a *formal* proof of the isomorphism but both sets are of the same cardinality and there's a 1:1 mapping between the "parts" of size $q$ in a given partition and the number of $q-cycles$ in the symmetric group. You can see that here: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_symmetric_group:S8

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, thanks for the link! I think I might not have been clear enough. I'm aware that the cycle type of a permutation in the symmetric group defines what partition it should be sent to (i.e. $(1, 3, 5)(2, 4)(6)(7, 8)$ has cycle type $(3,2,1,2)$ which forms the mapping to the partition: $(3,2,2,1)$). But I'm looking for properties of the **conjugacy group** that $(1, 3, 5)(2, 4)(6)(7, 8)$ belongs to in $S_8$ (which we can call $(1, 2, 3)(4, 5)(6, 7)$ for simplicity.

Comment: That should not be called an "isomorphism", because there is no structure that you are preserving. Rather, there is a bijective between the conjugacy classes of $S_n$ and the partitions of $n$, in that each partition determines a conjugacy class and vice-versa, and these relations are inverses of each other. But when you talk about "isomorphism" in the context of group theory, you are implicitly talking about a bijection that preserves the group structure. That's not what we have here.

Comment: What is a conjugacy group? Never heard of it. As is it now, the question in the title has been answered in the comments, and there is no question in the OP. If your question is something else, could you edit your post to make it clearer?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, that's a very good point. I suppose a bijection is a more apt term as there isn't any apparent structure that's being preserved by the mapping. Thanks!

Comment: @verret, I hope it's clear from context that when I said conjugacy *group* I meant conjugacy *class*. I simply misspoke when replying quickly. And I don't see how the question has been answered. Tanner linked to the definition of cycle type. Cycle type is a property of individual elements of $S_n$. I'm looking for studied properties of *cojugacy classes* in $S_n$ -not individual elements of said classes.

Comment: @BrianJoseph No, J.W.Tanner's link is about the proof that the cycle type is actually a property of a conjugacy class.

Comment: The cycle types ARE the conjugacy classes (as a few people have said already). To be perhaps more explicit: two elements in $S_n$ are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle type. What else would you like to know?

Comment: @lisyarus, verret, thanks for sticking with me. I'm not being clear. Yes, the cycle type of a conjugacy class (and of all of its elements by definition) *is* a property of the conjugacy class (and all of its elements too). But I hope you can understand it's not particularly useful information when the cycle type of a conjugacy class is defined as an [integer partition](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cycle_type) which is already known, given the bijection I'm making from partitions -which are also cycle types- to said conjugacy classes. I'm asking for more deep properties of said classes.